# Rofxord: how to change the endpoint and connect with API Azure Cognitive Service?

Tags: r, azure, api, azure-cognitive-services, rjson

I try to connect with Azure Cognitive Service using Roxford package. I got error propably due to wrong endpoint (after including Oxford Project into Azure Services there are several, region specific end points).

I got the key from personal account in Azure Cognitive Service project:

[image]

```
library(Roxford)
library(plyr)
library(rjson)
facekey <- "xxx"  #look it up on your subscription site
getFaceResponseURL("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/5/6/4/1147292-new-women-faces-wallpaper-2880x1800-for-phone.jpg",key= facekey)
#I got error
# {"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}
```

How to change the endpoint to the: "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Roxford` lib is the one here: https://github.com/flovv/Roxford/blob/master/R/videoAnalysis_LIB.R#L182

Then you can add the region when you call the method. Cognitive Services keys are dedicated to an Azure region, so you should use the same region when you use it. If you don't remember which region you choose when you generated the key, it's written in the overview in Azure portal.

Then when you use `getFaceResponseUrl`:

```
getFaceResponseURL <- function(img.url, key, region="westus")
```

Pass the region:

```
getFaceResponseURL("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/5/6/4/1147292-new-women-faces-wallpaper-2880x1800-for-phone.jpg", key=facekey, region="theAzureRegionOfYourKey")
```